# redirection not happening in AJAX POST method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following view page in ASP.NET MVC

```
 @model ProjectName.Model.Sample
 @{

 }
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        ..        
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        ..
      </div>
   </form>
  </div>
     <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
     <button type="button" class="ss" id="savebutton">Save</button>
     <button type="button" class="ssd">Clear</button>
     </div>
     </div> 

     <script type="text/javascript">

     $("#savebutton").click(function () {
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    url: '@Url.Action("AssignUsers", "Sample")',
                    data: { ... },               

                    success: function ()
                    {

                    },
                    error: {}
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
```

then I have following post method to catch the Ajax POST method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AssignUsers(...) 
    {
        try
        {
                if (sucess)
                {
                   // I have an Area call Account therefor try to direct like below
                  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Sample", new { area = "Account" });
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please try again.");
                }

                return View();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Then I replaced

`return RedirectToAction("Index", "Sample", new { area = "Account" });`

with

`return Redirect("~/Account/Sample/Index");`

but that once also not working.

After this success this not direct to desired location, whats wrong in my approach.

Comment: You making an ajax call. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. It never redirects. Do not use ajax - just do a normal submit (all you doing is degrading performance by returning all the html generated by your `Index()` method back to the client and tossing it away

Comment: @StephenMuecke but I have some values to pass when click Save button , I have to pass `int groupid`, `int[] users` to this post method , can I bind to a model that interger and array before I click this ?

Comment: I don't know what your data is, how its being generated or what your controller parameters are (impossible to help). Why are those values not just in the form controls?

Comment: You can use "UpdatedTargetId" to move another page in same view by refreshing element content just like <div> or etc. Otherwise you need to use ActionResult and generic request instead of ajax call.

Comment: @StephenMuecke here I added more details https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/446LG ,can I bind this to a model to similicity I didnt add many code here

Comment: So all your wanting to submit are the value of the `<select>` elements? Just use a normal form and submit (it is utterly pointless to use ajax)

Comment: You need to design your models correctly and create you view correctly so that it binds to your model, and then all you need is a POST method with a parameter `Sample model` and your model will be correctly bound with the selected values.

Comment: @StephenMuecke are you suggest to change like this 

 `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="~/Account/Sample/AssignUsers" method="post">
<button type="submit" class="ss" id="savebutton">Save</button>
</form>`

and remove ajax call ?

Comment: Yes, but your model and view are not correct to allow you to do this corretly, but based on what you have currently shown in the bitbucket, the POST method will need to be `public ActionResult AssignUsers(int groupID, int[] country)`.

Comment: Yep then How to bind values to this `int groupID, int[] country` in view page , without ajax call ?

can I do like this `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

 var assign_item = $("#assign_item").val();
 var group  = $('#groupvalue').val();
    });
</script>`

then in url `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="~/Account/Sample/AssignUsers/groupid=group , assignedusers = assign_item" method="post">` please advise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127764/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that you add your redirect action to your Javascript code, and catch it via Json on your controller:

```
$("#savebutton").click(function () {
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                url: '@Url.Action("AssignUsers", "Sample")',
                data: { ... },               

                success: function (result)
                {
                    if (result.isSuccess==false)
                    {
                      //Add your redirect code here:
                       window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Sample")';
                    }
                },
                error: {}
            });
        });
    }
```

And on your controller, you will catch it using Json:

```
if (sucess)
      {         
        return Json(new {isSuccess = false, message = "Your message here"});
      }
```